# SQL Server 2005 Express connection

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server

On my computer I had installed Windows XP Service Pack 2. Then I installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1 and then SQL Server 2008 r2 and SQL Server 2005 Express. Up to that I had no problem using SQL Server 2008 r2 and SQL Server 2005 Express.

After that I updated Windows XP Service Pack 2 to Service Pack 3, because I wanted to install Visual Studio 2010. Then I installed Visual Studio 2010.

Now there is no problem using SQL Server 2008 r2, but while using SQL Server 2005 Express it's showing this error message

> This version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express can only be used to connect to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2005 servers.(Microsoft.sqlServer.Express.connectionDlg)

I know that the SQL engine is the 2008 version so that the old version of SQL Server 2005 can't connect, but is there any solution for this problem? Can I install any newer service pack of 2005 SQL Server to solve this problem?

Comment: why do you want ss2005?

Comment: because client using ss2005

Comment: tell 'em to use 2008 (or preferably later) express.  they're all free